# iOS - UIPageViewController didFinishAnimating delegate method not called if animation is interrupted

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

My app has a layout of a `UIPageViewController` occupying most of the screen and a `UITabBar` sitting at the bottom.

I am facing an edge case where the user swipe left/right and tap on the `UITabBar` at the same time, it's basically when `UIPageViewController` is in transition, interrupt the transition by switching to a different screen. The following happens,

1. The `pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController])` delegate method is called.
2. But the `pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool)` delegate method is never called.
3. What's weirder is that after the user switches back to the `UIPageViewController` using `UITabBar`, `viewDidAppear` is called on the content ViewController which is not the one currently rendered on the screen.

For example,
I have 2 tabs on my `UITabBar` - `Tab1` and `Tab2`. The user is able to swipe between `VC1` and `VC2` in the `UIPageViewController` which is attached to `Tab1`, and `VC3` is attached to `Tab2`.

Now the user is on `Tab1` and `VC1` is displayed on the screen inside `UIPageViewController`. If the user swipes in `UIPageViewController` from `VC1` to `VC2` and taps on `Tab2` at the same time (you have to do this really quick). `pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController])` is called. But `pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool)` is not called.

Then if the user taps on `Tab1` and goes back to `UIPageViewController`. The `viewDidAppear` is called on `VC1` while `VC2` is actually rendered on the screen.

I understand this is an edge case and potentially a bug from Apple. Wondering if anyone has encountered this before and if there is any workaround/solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem.

What happens is that while transitioning if you change the tab then the ViewController changes. As a result the control shifts from the PageViewController to the new ViewController.
This is why the delegate callbacks stop.

If you switch back to the PageViewController you might notice one of two things :

- The initial page is loaded. This happens when you've swiped less than half way through the pages before switching tabs.
- The next page (page after the initial one) is loaded. This happens when you've swiped more than half way through the pages before switching tabs.

It's not exactly a bug, just the way control flows in Cocoa.

There isn't a fix as such but there is a workaround. You can disable interaction with the TabBarController while the animation is taking place and then enable it once it is finished.

Comment: This is exactly what I've encountered and I have also applied the disable logic to all elements on the screen other than `UIPageViewController` as a workaround. The reason why I categorized it as a bug is that, in case of bullet point two, even though the second page is rendered on the screen. `ViewDidLoad` is called on the first page instead of second.

Comment: That's strange. For me when I begin swiping, the viewDidLoad of the next page is called. I think that should be the case as the page needs to be loaded first and then presented. Also, once all pages are loaded, viewDidLoad (for the pages) is never called again. I can't seem to reproduce your bug.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I meant viewDidAppear